# Wagtail - Programmatically Edit Existing Page

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, wagtail

How do I edit an existing Wagtail page programmatically? 
There's a few explanations of how to add new pages, but I still can't seem to figure out how to edit a single field on an existing page. I'd like to use the 'Title' field as reference.

This seems to be completely undocumented officially, but there is a nice written guide to adding pages programmatically [here](https://timonweb.com/tutorials/how-to-add-wagtail-page-programmatically-via-python-script/).

Comment: It shouldn't be different than editing any other model instance. Have you tried getting the page using `my_page = Page.objects.get(...)` and then setting the field, i.e. `my_page.my_field = 'new value'` and `my_page.save()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wagtail is just a Django app. A big one, and it overrides some Django features. So it might be nicer to say Wagtail is built on top op Django. Anyway, Wagtail is just Django.

Wagtail content types like pages, images and documents and all your custom content types (snippets etc) are Django models. So the Django documentation on [models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/) and [making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/) is the documentation you are looking for.

Here is an example for setting the page title programatically:

```
page = Page.objects.get(id=1)
page.title = 'Some title'
page.save()
```